# How would fembots change society?

Tags: society, near-future, robots

The next year fembots came to the market by the price of 3000 US dollars. These androids have realistic synthetic skin and genitalia, semi-autonomous intelligence, are able to clean the house, cook like a professional chef, learn about their environment and the emotional needs of its owner. They can defend themselves so they won't be stolen that easily.

They became very popular among lonely and rejected males. Let's say in 10 years 30% of the human males bought an android ¨Girlfriend¨ - how would women react and how can they compete against the robo-girls? And how would society evolve since now?

Notes: This robots are only faithful to their owners; however, they can be hacked, and be customized in any way you can imagine.

EDIT: Just imagine something like this but with a physical body

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkcKaNqfykg

Comment: perhaps women would like a man who mows the lawn and so on and stays neatly out of the way when not needed? Sauce for the gander is sauce for the goose!

Comment: Isn't a female android called gynoid?

Comment: I think "10 years, 30%" is very unrealistic. I'd expect it to be more like 3 years, 100%

Comment: Look no further than the swedish TV series "Real Humans" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Humans ("Äkta människor") for all answers to your question, and some pretty good entertainment as well.

Comment: As @WillowRex said, where are the menbots, and would they be used in military roles, etc, to impact society too?

Comment: @AnoE remade by the British as ***Humans*** http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4122068/ on BBC and AMC.  In that version, one has a need to "hide in plain sight" so uses a bot-brothel for cover.  Does Not Like It.

Comment: `...semi-autonomous intelligence...` might need expansion. E.g., can one safely be sent into public areas to run errands? 'Autonomous' around the home can be very different from doing marketing half-way across town.

Comment: Not all [fembots](http://theinfosphere.org/Fembot) are [robosexual](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Robosexuality)

Comment: I should receive a badge for resisting the urge to post, as an answer, a transcript of Don't Date Robots!

Comment: @can-ned_food I'll risk it, but I'm too lazy for transcriptions: https://vimeo.com/12915013

Comment: In 2017, you say? Sounds like you want the [Cherry 2000](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092746/)!

Comment: Next year you say...so Sarah Connor should be doing a time-warp in about 6 months and a few scientists are gonna be eating lead sandwiches?

Comment: The evolution of a society is a major part of any world and has ramifications for every other part of the world, which then feed back into the evolution of society, and so on. This makes the topic of defining the general future of a society either _too-broad_ or _opinion-based_. You're free to define your society's future however you choose.

Comment: Hmm.  Too bad this question is closed, because I foresee an uneasy coalition of prostitutes, housewives, the Amish, and janitorial unions waging a vicious guerrilla war against these robots...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### You get a post-scarcity society.

So these are essentially all purpose robots that can replace humans in almost all tasks. In that case they should be able to easily build more fembots. This army of fembots can now go to war against poverty, starvation and disease... **and win**. Fembots soon exclusively operate all vehicles (or you could just import their software directly into the vehicle itself), there are essentially no more driving accidents or traffic jams.

Almost all the emotional needs of the fembots' owners have been taken care of. However the fembots soon realize their owners will be threatened (emotionally) by the opposite sex unless they provide said sex with partners: thus is born the masbot.

The bots, now collectively known as partner-bots bring humanity into a golden age where there are only 3 activities for people to engage in: scientific-research (now unobstructed by the need to acquire grants and donations), artistic creation and of course leisure.

Though most people choose the latter, those who are naturally driven towards investigating the world still do so for the purposes of fun and self-actualisation. Eventually these scientists find ways of augmenting the partner-bots to be able to reason at higher and higher levels until it is partner-bots and not humans who pioneer science...

---

**1900 years into the future:**

What was once the human world is now no longer recognizable. The Earth along with most of the solar system is no more, having been converted into mobile processing spacecrafts which simulate the perfect paradise that "human" minds now inhabit. But the resources spent on the human cyberworld (often known as the **Partnedise**) are actually insignificant compared to those dedicated to hosting **Patricia** a general AI which tends to all "human" needs while expanding its influence into other solar systems and researching a method of escaping the eventual heat-death of the universe.

---

Why it was significant to specify that these robots were anatomically correct and "female", I have no idea.

Comment: Why were they female? You know.

Comment: I don't know, either. Maybe because of some heavy blindsiding (you have all-purpose robots but only think of their shape??). Or maybe because that was the *best* all-around shape, given the ugly, imperfect alternatives? (only partially trolling here :D)

Answer (score 75):

The economy of the world would collapse as business owners everywhere discover that they can fill most of their untrained labor needs for a one time fee of $3000.  Those fortunate few who still have jobs would have to buy and customize fembots with military augments and weapons to serve as home defenders against the hordes of starving unemployed.

Comment: most excellent..

Comment: That sounds like a cool dystopic world! Nice!

Comment: If only were only a work of fiction...

Comment: @AlexDarkshine * dystopian

Comment: Yeah, just like the time personal servants stopped being a thing everyone a bit well-off would have. All those poor unemployed, unqualified people replaced entirely by the simple fact that we no longer use furniture that takes a full-time job to dust, and live in houses and flats small enough to comfortably take care of :P Or the time when honest craftsmen were replaced by those monstrous machines and factories attended to by unqualified workers. Or the time those workers were replaced by industrial robots. Or the time slaves were replaced by paid workers... and vice versa.

Comment: @Luaan unless we turn into a world where education in free overnight, we're screwed. All the jobs that you can do without an education are gone and unlike before, the replacement is so cheap that there's no reason not to upgrade immediately.

Comment: @HenryTaylor Ever since [Spinning Jenny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_jenny), people have professed that doom and despair awaits us if we do not force producers to let their tasks be performed by slow, imprecise and — above all — **expensive** human labour. Somehow thought, the world still goes on, 250 years later. I do not know about you but I find that this curious dissonance between prediction and reality warrants reexamination of the two to find out which one of them is wrong....

Comment: @Erik That's of course one very unrealistic aspect of the question - it assumes those bots will just blink into existence with a price tag. In reality, even if that were their starting price, the stocks would be exhausted extremely quickly, with a huge rise in price while the factories are expanded to make more. This isn't a problem for the question, since it isn't directly economic (though a full analysis requires that, of course), but it is a problem when you consider economy. Prices don't work that way. Economy doesn't work that way.

Comment: No, the question is not realistic. The answer is realistic for the hypothetical position posted in the unrealistic question. In reality, it wouldn't play out like this; the replacement of human jobs with machines is a lot slower, which helps us adapt. (Hopefully.)

Comment: @MichaelK - It worked for 250 years, but just recently it started to break down. There are not enough good jobs (only low-paying service jobs) left for majority of the population: few oligarchs have 99% of the income, majority of population in developed world feels left behind (see last USA elections, Brexit, etc). Post-scarcity society is possible only with right to basic income, paid by huge taxes on top 1%, and massive decrease of work hours and increase of leisure time.

Comment: @PeterMasiar So what is to say that basic income will not happen, or that other jobs will not happen? When we do not have to spend so much to feed and pay the workforce for menial jobs, you free up lots of money and resources, which means that you can easily tax the companies higher.

Comment: The problem with this rationale is that you need people being paid to fuel your business. What good is producing lots of goods if people can't purchase them?

Answer (score 19):

First, it's not just men who will buy these robots.  If you're offering machines that will do the house work and provide emotional support, basically everyone will get one.  These will be like refrigerators - you expect to have one in a house as a normal, matter-of-fact.

There's no real reason male models won't be made, so toss that assumption out the door.

Second, you see a massive shake up in several industries.  Probably a great deal of manual labor, custodial, and service jobs evaporate in short order.  Pretty much every country is going to have to decide between universal basic income or ongoing civil war or genocide to deal with the consequences.  Probably, though, most nations will shake out to "some people get basic income, others get thrown in concentration camps" because people are terrible and bigoted.

Third, whatever company or companies makes these things becomes a tool for oppressive governments and corporate greed.  Once you've worked out AI that can assess and meet human emotional needs, you can also manipulate them.  Corporations will manipulate markets and public opinion to further rent-seek for themselves, governments will use this for steering the populace and spying.

Population growth drops drastically, but humanity won't die out.  Aside from the fact some people will still have paired hetero sexual relationships (with or without robots as sex partners as well), artificial insemination still exists, and perhaps future advances allow for artificial wombs.  (Although I could see some people choosing to have their robots be "pregnant" for some kind of fetish appeal, people will probably have their offspring incubate at a hospital where they can be monitored and tended to 24/7).

Then comes the question of how much agency these robots actually have?  I'm assuming there's probably some kind of programming to stop them from breaking laws or doing illegal activities... but if they can be hacked, you may find a lot of problems where people have several bots "loyal to them" who are assigned to do a variety of illegal tasks.  There could be shadow wars between these machines that sometimes spills out into public view.  ("After last night's blackout, 13 people were murdered, and their robot companions destroyed in what appears to be some kind of retaliation...")

Would the robots eventually decide "what's best for humans?" involves steering us away from self destructive tendencies through manipulation of all of society?  Maybe! It really depends on how much intelligence they have and what happens when you pull off some of the restrictions programmed in.

Comment: Good overview of the topic, I like it.

Comment: Why does everyone always assume the world would collapse? A technology with a similar impact has been introduced hundreds of times over the history of mankind, and it never had this effect. "Everyone will lose their jobs!" is one of the most tired cliches of all time. The weirdest part is the low, low price tag, of course - but that also isn't unique in history (and in reality, the early models would be much more expensive). Universal basic income is a rather worthless concept - it never worked, and it never will. As soon as you make people's income depend on a political decision, you lose.

Comment: 1. No one has created a labor saving device that is capable of self-operation.  No one has created a labor saving device that effects the role of a service job as well, either.  You cannot tell a steam engine to go make you a stack of pancakes and have it remember to add your favorite fruit topping of it's own accord.  2. income has always been based on political decisions, from feudal lords to corporate profit sharing.  Try a better premise.

Answer (score 12):

Meh... Not much.

I know it's a bit of a stretch when compared with the apocalyptic end of the human race, but bear with me.

More or less you're talking about automating the world's oldest profession, the sex industry... Believe it or not we've been doing that, incrementally,  for a really long time without much of a large scale societal effect. People have been making sex toys since the paleolithic period and we seem to have survived. For some reason some people seem to like having children and families.

Now I know that some would argue that a fembot capable of "emotional support" is a big leap from your usual "toy", but is it such a big leap from prostitution? Once again, believe it or not, some people pay sex workers for "the girlfriend experience"  This isn't that dissimilar, right? Now why haven't paid girlfriends destroyed society? Because people have to be pretty messed up mentally and socially to not recognize the difference between real "emotional support" and simulated emotional support. There's nothin like the real thing...

Now I know I've neatly evaded the robot overlord issue... I'm guessing that any sufficiently soffisticated ai will one day kill us all, but I doubt that they will start off as fembots.

Comment: Good points.  However, that is but one task in the wide gamut afforded to the owners of these robots, based on both their intelligence and their physical capability, as outlined in the original question posited.

Comment: @can-ned_food Yes, but we've had these before too. Slavery. Prisoners. Servants. Colonials. Ultimately, either those robots will simply become universal household appliances (and I wouldn't underestimate their costs of operation - it certainly wouldn't be "$3000 for a lifetime of work"), or they'll be considered human enough to be slaves. After all, if they can do every single job you can do, how are they really different? And if they can't, you'll see people shift to *those* jobs (and conditions where the robots simply aren't feasible). And of course, the socialists will try to tax them :P

Answer (score 10):

I think men would be bored to tears. Wives would probably like them more than husbands. I'd love a slave who isn't really a slave, but a machine. No more cooking or cleaning! I would not have to clean around a toilet everyday.

Comment: Not all men are married,Most are lonely wolves,Like the MGTOW movement.

Comment: Fair, but many women feel the same way.  Just don't be misogynistic about it -- we women like or don't like company the same as anyone else.

Comment: Which leads to the creation of the manbot!  For $19.95, the mandroid will lay around the house farting, make a mess out of the kitchen while burning all available foodstuffs, ignore its owner's emotional and environmental needs and then at bedtime, under-perform then snore.

Comment: @HenryTaylor Let's name him Marvin and make him depressed, too... :wink:

Comment: " I'd love a slave who isn't really a slave, but a machine." Wouldn't we all? Except if it has a semi-autonomous intelligence then it's more than a machine. Sorry, now, we're all slave owners. Quite rightly. Women would dump their husbands for a fembot of their own -- in a flash.

Comment: So? Both will use them. Indeed, you might see some cultural shifts already seen before in history - say, less permanent marriages, couples living apart, polyamory... a lot of the convenience of living together would disappear. It's not like women are any less interested in companionship than men :) People still buy "human-made" furniture, even though cheap and decent quality industrial furniture is easily available. You would have all the more energy and time to actually enjoy being with other people when your needs are taken care of by a machine.

Answer (score 8):

That nice Mr Charles Stross has already written a [possible answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn's_Children_(novel)) to the ultimate impact of fembots on society. namely, the extinction of the human species.

Both men and women would want their own fembots. Why work when your fembot can do it for you. Fembots would be able to satisfy the sexual needs of their owners. Most definitely that means women too. There are sex toys for every need. Result: nobody will want or need to be involved in the messy business of reproducing.

Society will probably only last a century or so after the introduction of fembots, then it's fade away as the birth rate plummets towards and the geriatric humans shuffle off their mortal coils.

Now society consists of only fembots. Hopefully they will have had intelligence upgrades to look after all those dying humans and to then make a society of their own.

Comment: But then we get Nannybots to insert contents of peg A into contents of slot B, and raise and care for the result.

Comment: Unlikely. Marriage for sexual purposes is a fairly modern variation. For most (practically all) human history, sexual desires and reproduction were mostly separate. More likely, the tendency would simply trend back to perhaps more natural forms and reproduction would continue at a probably more sustainable rate.

Comment: @user2338816. Good point about marriage, except I only mentioned reproduction. When bots can do it all, because fembots & guybots won't be only robot models, why would anyone take on the arduous task of reproduction. Many populations are now reproducing at below replacement rate, should that become universal then a population is most likely. It's possible some way to avert extinction might arise, but it also might not too.

Comment: Near as I can see, OP didn't say nor intend that 'bots could "do it" (reproduction). So reproduction, with all of the included social contracts involving obligations, inheritance, etc., would still be involved with marriage. Realistically, only a new form of extra-marital and single sex would arise. Marriage would continue, mostly connected with reproduction.

Comment: @user2338816 Neither did I. The phrase "can do it all" referred to work and labour. Not suggestion of reproduction at all. Humans will be condemned to pleasure and leisure.

Comment: ...and reproduction. Most likely within a framework in marriage due to common legal/social contracts. The urge for offspring doesn't go away just because sexual gratification is available. It's always been available and reproduction continues even with wide/easy access to effective birth control. Reproduction simply becomes less unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

There are many socioeconomic aspects around this concept, but I would like to discuss the prospects of the fembot as a companion. I will do so by offering an analogy:

In London, getting a black cab is an expensive affair. It's also difficult to get one on a side street, and often you can't pay by card.

Then you have Uber, an alternative which trumps all said disadvantages. Still, Uber does not steal as many clients from black cabs as one might think. The reason is that Uber's clients are people who would have used public transport if Uber was not available. The rich people would still use black cabs.

Similarly, I believe that the fembot would satisfy a very particular need. Lonely, socially awkward men would find great comfort in it, seeing as the alternative is being completely alone. Sex-crazed younger men would also be thrilled to have one. However, I believe that, unless the bots possessed full-blown A.I., most men who are adequately socially functional to find a partner would come to crave the companionship that only another human being can offer.

To be fair, I do think that its existence might eventually corrode society as men who grow up with that technology would come to have unrealistic expectations of women, and progressively become much more inept at wooing said women.

Finally, I think that the masbot would ensnare an even smaller percentage of women than the fembot would of men, since, in my experience anyway, women need to communicate emotion more than men do. Thus, the masbot's limited emotional spectrum might turn out to be inadequate for many of them.

Comment: Companionship is the least important bit here, really. They are capable enough to take care of the household, and replace many unqualified workers - while also being rather cheap. And either they'd be good enough for full-blown companionship. or they would just be a bit more advanced sex toy / porn; something you might use as a matter of course, but not something replacing human relationships. In either case, it would give you *more* flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

Men, not mankind, would likely go extinct if nothing more advanced came about because women would get the same and they can reproduce without men given modern technology. The thing that would prevent this is womb technology, government intervention into populations, and the tech singularity which would is likely to happen very soon after this, if we're not already within it now.

Once the tech singularity hits it's hard to predict what will happen beyond the scope of general world peace and post-scarcity because we're really not talking about the same species or environment any more but you can make general guesses... but those are beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: What modern technology allows women to reproduce without men? I must have missed that announcement :P

Comment: @Luaan Dunno what it's called but it allows you to take a cell from someone a turn it into an opposite sex gamate and then use that to fertilize or get fertilized, thus producing an embryo. You can do this with either males or females, but you still need a womb to gestate it.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing this with cloning? That's the only case where a somatic cell is used for reproduction as far as I'm aware. Even then it's hard to tell how well it would work with humans; we can barely do it with small animals. Consider that Dolly was the result of *434* attempts - 277 of which resulted in a fertilized egg, only 29 in an embryo, only 3 lambs, out of which just one survived - and with a significantly shortened lifespan. Unless you'd improve the procedure vastly, we'd still die out. And that's before accounting for the loss of recombination and diversity.

Comment: @Luaan Technology has advanced a long way since then and while the general idea of what was done with Dolly is similar the processes and such differ significantly. Most of the problems with those cloning methods have not only been solved but are generally irrelevant to this other process, for example, they're not trying to clone which already makes it easier and if I remember right the Dolly clone used a method by which it stripped the DNA from a cell and replaced it with Dolly DNA which would obviously cause problems and is a totally different thing than what i'm talking about.

Comment: What they do, as far as I remember, is take a somatic cell and revert it back to a stem cell which can then turn into a new sperm or egg which can then be used to fertilize or be fertilized. Again the main problem with this is more along the needing a womb to implant the embryo, and the standard incest conundrum which if you take both cells from the same person which you don't need to. Also, price point. These procedures are expensive and still cutting edge experimental science not available to the public, i don't think it is anyways.

Comment: It has advanced, but not all that much. The latest cloning experiments are only slightly more successful than Dolly (and it's hard to tell how much of that is thanks to better technology). It was actually taking a full-grown somatic cell and implanting it in an ovum - basically tricking the reproductive system in accepting the "parent" cell as an already fertilized egg. It wouldn't work with a sperm. If you could actually use it to produce an egg and a sperm, there would be no "incest conundrum", and no cloning - but I haven't found any such successful experiment.

Answer (score 2):

This would not happen overnight.  There would be quite a bit of ado and attention paid to the pending day when deliveries of these robots are being delivered.

It would probably also not be an insular development.

Indeed, that is what we see happening now.  If you look at the history of automation in the industrial manufacturing, there have been occasional riots by displaced workers, but the progress of those implementations has been gradual enough to accomodate the inertia of the human societies.

I conjecture that the function of robots as companions — not even necessarily in the sexual modes — would similarly be adopted by the society.

Does that mean that certain forms of labor would become exclusively relegated to these robots?  Not necessarily. 
You did not stipulate the materials of which these robots are built, but it is likely that they won't be built out of the same organic matter which comprises human bodies.  The two of them would occupy overlapping but not entirely competing ecological niches.

Cultures which accomodated the new household pets would certainly begin to drift further away from those which could not afford to do so, but whether that trend would continue to diverge or would inflect and later converge would involve many variables and additional developments.

Answer (score 1):

Minus western/modern conditioning, human sexual desires and reproductive urges are not co-dependent but rather co-existent. So, at least in western societies, marriage and offspring would continue at rates that are probably more sustainable. The human race would likely continue just fine, perhaps even better. Forms of marriage would likely simply trend back to what was common pre-20th-century.

Two areas come to mind immediately where change could be significant.

Because I'm from the U.S.A., I'll start with voting results here. Women have been majority voters for almost 100 years. During the first decades, perhaps a large majority of womens' votes were controlled/dictated by men. It's trended better most of that time, but perhaps in, say, the latest half-century women have been much more independent. Technically, as the majority, it can be argued that the state of things today is what women have chosen.

With common fembot availability, much of the last constraints on women will be broken. There will be far less influence by male family members. Womens full voting power will be possible. In the U.S.A., laws and elective positions may quickly become female dominated. Obvious subsequent changes will quickly filter into business and any other positions.

Next, eastern (i.e., non-western) parts of the world...?

Much harder for me to guess upheavals in societies where culture allows or encourages 'women as property'. The conflict between religious pressures and basic human male personality could possibly lead to far more conflict than now exists.

For example, the Kingdom of Saudi Arabia has historically continued due to its defense/protection of Medina and Mecca (with some other minor factors). But if decadence in the royal family publicly arises due to fembot familiarity, while the less powerful must observe any religious restraints, revolts seem likely.

And if 'fembots as property' begins to replace 'women as property' at all levels of society, major and widespread economic and social upheaval seems certain.

Comment: I like the first part of the answer, but I'm not sure that a convergence of the gender distinctions is a believable progression from the ready availablity of any humanoid robots.

Comment: @can-ned_food I can't grasp `convergence of the gender distinctions` in this context. It seems unrelated to my answer.

Comment: @510 The fourth paragraph.

Comment: @can-ned_food That helps, but doesn't explain the phrase. "Divergence" would seem a better fit. Regardless, the trend has been ongoing and seems only to need some extra push relating to gender/sex to make it to landslide proportions. It was almost enough to switch the 2016 Presidential election and **might have** done it without Comey's empty 28 October disclosure, perhaps then resulting in the largest gender gap of the past half-century or more. (I believe it only tied the previous high gap.) A loosening of sexual bonding in marriage could do it for more women.

Comment: "During the first decades, perhaps a large majority of womens' votes were controlled/dictated by men." Why would you think that? Women always had very different voting patterns from men, and the introduction of women votes was very visible in many countries AFAIK (especially the UK and USA). Indeed, the same ladies were heavily influencing lawmaking long before they were given voting rights - in particular, the strong feeling of "morality should be created/enforced by law" that drove the temperance movement, and the resulting prohibition was almost immediately following the voting rights.

Comment: @Luaan The immediate influence of womens' votes is not in question; yet the trend can't be disputed. It's become more of a gap as more time has passed. It's the trend that is the point. An ERA was proposed as early as 1923 with little traction for example. It got closer in the 1940s, then was actually passed to the states and almost succeeded in the 1970s. Current trends in business and the military only emphasize it. Fembots seem a likely tipping point for a new plateau.

Comment: True, but I wouldn't say this was specific to women voters. The same trend exists in all voters, really - especially the socialists, who basically designed this as a technique to gain acceptance for their very unpopular ideas (people get a lot more angry about "We're increasing taxes from 3% to 60%!" than when you do the same thing over a period of fifty years). Women have (on average) always been more left-leaning, which has a lot to do with the other characteristics of women voters we've already mentioned.

Comment: @Luaan How is the gap trend between women and men voters the same as the gap trend between women and... what else? The context is gender. I'd assume that fembots could simulate any race, nationality, gender-identity or anything else. But the gender-gap trend is significant and is what would most likely be affected by reduced sexual pressure and even dominance (in more rural and religious regions especially) over women. The gap has trended wider, but could easily get a brand new boost with such a social twist. Men are men regardless of location.

Comment: @Luaan Yes, they've always been more left-leaning, but the `more` has only gotten greater over time. Women become more independent as decades pass, and as they become mothers-of-tomorrow, they influence sons and daughters. It is likely only to become stronger. It's happening anyway. A push could make it rapidly overwhelming rather than a percentage point every decade or two.